# Regex for matching every 3 word string

Tags: php, regex

I want to return matches for every instance of a three word phrase. I'm not worried about proper grammar right now. I'm more interested in how to achieve the 'multi-pass' nature of the request.

```
$string = "one two three four five";

$regex = '/(?:[^\\s\\.]+\\s){3}/ui';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
```

Will only return:

`one two three`

Needed results:

`one two three`

`two three four`

`three four five`

Comment: What is the output with regex in question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it putting your pattern in a lookahead:

```
$string = "one two three four five";

$regex = '~\b(?=([^\s.]+(?:\s[^\s.]+){2}))~u';

preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. It's splitting on hyphens as well even though the character class is matching on `^\s` (anything but space). How would you solve for that?

Comment: @atb: it can be solved replacing the word-boundary `\b` with `(?<![^\s.])` *(not preceded by a character that is not a white-space or a dot)*

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
$string = "one two three four five";
$arr = explode(" ", $string);
               
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) 
    echo $arr[$i], " ", $arr[$i + 1], " ", $arr[$i + 2], "\n";
```

Outputs:

> one two three
>
> two three four
>
> three four five